# Seven levels of information hierarchy - UITableView - iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, user-interface, user-experience

I have an information hierarchy that consists of seven levels. Is it appropriate to use UITableView? I'm just conscious that this may be too deep for users to navigate the information. The information is a decision tree for Antibiotic prescribing.

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

You possibly mean that each level is represented by UITableView, while all the levels can be browsed through UINavigationController.

I think it can work, as far as UX is concerned, provided the user has enough knowledge of this hierarchy so not to get lost in it.

The question is: do you envision other possibilities of showing that information?

Comment: That's correct. Yes, I was thinking of allowing the more advanced users to see all the levels in a form of a chart also.

Answer (score 1):

To have 7 levels of hierarchy within a table view structures is indeed possible but pretty deep and inefficient. You have to think like your user and what kind of experience it would be for them. Normally 4 at the most. As suggestion, you should probably subclass or sectionyour Model to more efficient navigational structure.